# Render React UI in play framework

Tags: java, scala, reactjs, playframework

I am trying to use React to render my UI in Play framework, but it doesn`t work. The same code just saved as .html file and opened directly can works normally, but if I place it in my play framework project as path: ./app/views/hello.scala.html, it just show title normally but nothing shown on my page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="./react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="./react/browser.min.js"></script>
    <title>React Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather all the js are loaded properly. check your assert path

```
<script src="assets/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="assets/react/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/react/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems these js file are not loaded correctly, because IDEA said that "JSX is used without importing React". I have checked my asset path but nothing wrong was found.